# resize wrapper/mask on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, wrapper, scrollto

Any ideas on how i can re-size my wrapper and mask on browser re-size?
right now its stopping the mask once its loaded, so basically when i scroll content, its cut off.
Please see [here](http://www.andym.ca) for an example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').click(function () {

        $('a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        current = $(this);

        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      

        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });

});

function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

    $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);

}
```

Comment: why not let the flow of elements define the page size instead of wrapping everything in a fixed height?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how to recreate the issue you're having, when I go to the link listed above?

Comment: load window, then resize browser, then click on another link...e.g about us.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really require javascript. I would put in a media query (when you switch to your mobile styling) that sets your #wrapper, #mask and #item1 to:

```
height: auto !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches with the mask if you just let css handle it as a fixed object. If you do that, you can pull a lot of that code out of your resize function and things will run quite a bit faster.

```
#mask{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url(semi-transparent.png);
}
```

Same with your wrapper items. Just set width %100 and let css do the heavy lifting...

```
.item {
  width:100%;
}
```

So now your resize function is down to...

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  $('#wrapper').css({width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height()})
    .scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);
});
```

As for the wrapper itself, I'm not entirely clear on what the problem is. If you can post a demo or jsfiddle, I'll update my answer.

Comment: oops.. I see the demo link now.

Comment: ill try moving the mask and item js to css, so it may make it a little faster.
do you see the issue though? if you load the screen regular size...then resize screen and click on another button...the wrapper is set to the origional load, and cuts the content off.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I'm not seeing any color when I hover over `id='mask'` in Firebug when the page loads. Just `id='item1'` turns color in Firebug when the page loads. When you resize the browser window, mask shows color and its CSS is crossed out. Additionally, you have loads of console errors in Firebug. Although we would like to help, we're not going to build your entire website for you. Use Firebug to debug your code first, then get back to us. Thanks.